# Rails: Creating form with arbitrary number of text-inputs for multi-object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm building an online recipe book in rails, so I've thrown together an overly simplified rails app to get a proof of concept. In this app, there are only three models: Recipe, Ingredient and Step. A recipe has many ingredients and many steps, but there's no way to tell how many ingredients or steps will be needed until any new recipe is created and populated.

The traditional way of creating a new instance of any model is to have a page with a form to gather all the necessary information for each instance. However, it would be arduous and time-consuming to submit 20 different forms for one recipe that has 20 steps.

**How can I create a form with, say, 10 text inputs (one for each step in the directions)... and then break each input string up into it's own Step object when the form is submitted?** I can then use the same technique for the recipe's ingredients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only way to set up a multi-class, multi-instance creation is to mix the model-backed Recipe form with some other non-model-backed custom tags for the form. To get the arbitrary number of input fields, I just used jquery to change the name of each input and add in a new one to the DOM whenever a "+" button is clicked. I created such a button for both ingredients and steps, and I used the same JS to limit the number of ingredient and step fields the buttons can create.

When the form is submitted, the Recipe object is first created (with strong params that throw out anything non-model-backed). That Recipe object association is used to parse the other values and create objects for Ingredient and Step right there within the Recipe#create action. I handle rearrangement and validation of form-submitted data in private methods in the Recipe controller.

If anyone knows a better solution to the problem, please suggest.